# How to update Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2

I'm trying to update Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm using the webupd8team repository, but my old install of Sublime is not getting overwritten. So I end up with Sublime Text 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 installed. When I run sudo apt-get remove sublime-text* it only uninstalls the 2.0.2 version. How can I either uninstall the 2.0.1 version or update so that it overwrites it with 2.0.2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just delete 2.0.1 manually? Alternatively, you could download the tarball from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Comment: I'm fairly new to Linux. How could I delete 2.0.1 manually?

Comment: Before we get to the command line way, have you tried uninstalling 2.0.1 through the graphical interface to your package manager? Sorry I don't know the name, I'm not terribly familiar with Ubuntu - I'm mostly working on redhat/centos/fedora-type systems these days...

Comment: I think you have enough rep - if you're still having problems, please [join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33107/sublime-text)

Answer (score 17):

I also ran across this issue and found a 3rd party repo. This updated and installed the newest version of sublimetext 2.0.2 flawlessly. I am posting the directions here but please take the time to read all the documentation as things might have changed since this post.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/sublime

Check your ubuntu version first. This repository is ONLY for: Natty  Oneiric  Precise  Quantal  Raring

```
lsb_release -a
```

To install this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: If you already have Sublime Text 2 already installed, this works to upgrade as well.  Just change `sudo apt-get install sublime-text` to `sudo dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PPA for Sublime Text 2:

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2

But remember, that you will be integrating a new third-party-repository into your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I experienced,  I had also installed Sublime with the webup8team ppa.  Pre "Build 2221", the ppa installed sublime text at: **/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/**, it then added a bash file launcher: */usr/bin/sublime-text* to start Sublime.  I recently updated Sublime to "Build 2221".  It was installed at **/opt/sublime_text_2/** .  However, the launcher was not updated to point to the new location.  Which is probably the discrepancy you have experienced.  Here is how I fixed on my setup:

Edit the bash file launchers (I'm not sure which one is the right one for you, so edit both to be safe)

```
gedit /usr/bin/sublime-text
gedit /usr/bin/subl
```

Update the location

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

Comment: Better yet, here is a [bash file](https://gist.github.com/dsandstrom/5753864) I created that will look for a project file in the current directory if no arguments given.